# Build a project remotely but pick the code from local machine through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm running jenkins on my local machine. I need to build and run a project on remote machine as a slave.

I have my project(Java code) in my local machine where the Jenkins is running. So Now when I build the project it looks for the code in my slave machine and says it's not able to find the build.xml in my slave machine.

I want to be able to have Jenkins looks for the code in my local machine and build it in my slave machine and run in the slave machine.

Is that possible? if yes pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [copy artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). You can create 2 jobs - 1st one to just check out the source code from your repo/version control/workspace. The second job (which runs on the slave `restrict where this job can be run inside the job config`) can copy those files automatically to the `...remote slave/workspace` and then you do whatever you want with them.

This will do what you want, but as Mark O'Çonnor mentions, the idea is you commit the changes to your repository and then the other machine checks it out.

Answer (score 4):

You do not state which version control system you are using? Jenkins has version control plugins for Git, Subversion, etc...

The idea is that you commit and push your changes to your source code repository and the Jenkins slave will automatically pull down the code and compile if anything has changed.

Comment: Actually the java code is not in any version control system. I haven't added it yet. The code in on my local drive.

Comment: No revision control?? Absolutely essential, well worth learning how to setup and use something like Git. The investment in time will pay back in spades.